# How do I load multiple JSON files in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, load

I need to load multiple different JSON files.Now I use many AJAX to load them one by one, according to a list of their file name. But if I add a new JSON, I should change the list by myself. How can I load JSON files with code automatically?

Comment: What do you have, what did you try?

Comment: How and where do you get the list of filenames?

Comment: I use a .bat to get all filenames and save them as .txt

Comment: I am trying to make a 3d model display website that updated in real time

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1:**

A possible solution is to create a `JSON file that contains all file names`. Then you just have to `update the JSON file` instead of the list.

**solution 2:**

In the case where the file names are like `file1.json`, `file2.json`, ..., you can try to `get them with a loop` and `leave it at the first AJAX resource not found exception`.

Comment: If someone was sending JSON file to me, could I use code to update this JSON file that contains all file names? I'm new in this, thank you!

Comment: It depends, on how someone sent you the file (manually ? file transfer via the website ?) and how your website works (server-side rendering or not ?)